# .net standard format specifier to equivalent custom format

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to convert a standard number format specifier into it's equivalent custom format, e.g. `n2` depending on the current culture might be `#,##0.00`.

Basically is there a function that converts one to the other?

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: Did you look into the NumberFormatInfo Class?

Comment: Yes I did but couldn't see anything that might help.

Comment: It seems no such function exists in .NET. It is possible to write your own taking all the properties of NumberFormatInfo.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find one line solution to format as `#,##0.00`. Adding an extra `0` after 3 digits causing the issue, so I did split this task in extra steps and format looks as `#,###.00`

```
int n2 = 123;

// adding extar '0' at the end
string result = String.Format("{0}", n2).PadRight(4, '0');

// convert result back to int.
n2 = Int32.Parse(result);

// Format: #,###.00
Console.WriteLine("Format: #,###.00 \t" + 
                   n2.ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```